# Display legend of WMS in layers panel in full extent

Tags: qgis, wms, layers, legend, panel

When loading a WMS layer from e.g. http://www.wms.nrw.de/geobasis/wms_nw_dgk5 the legend of the layer with larger desciptions is displayed in the layer panel not to its full extent (see picture). When scrolling down, the layer collapse and so it is not possible to read the lower parts. Is there a possiblity to change?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just pull up the [pdf](https://www.bezreg-koeln.nrw.de/brk_internet/geobasis/sonstige/deutsche_grundkarte/zeichenerklaerung.pdf), that's more convenient.

Also, DGK is outdated, you should use DTK-data.

Comment: DGK is ment as an example, the same problem is when loading DTK data or other open maps.